# How to customize default screen of React-Native-lock?

Tags: react-native

[image]

I'd love to change contents such as image, label, button, css.
Is it possible?
If so, how should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is all they have in their React Native wrapper library and if you take a look at how they process the `options` object, it is not a lot of UI-related options:

https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock/blob/56a705ee4ab395730fb5e6a2beb356fb4853117c/ios/A0RNLock/Core/A0LockReact.m#L71-L151

If you want to customize the look you would have to make Native modules bridged to React Native by subclassing their native components, which you can find here: https://github.com/auth0/Lock.iOS-OSX/tree/master/Lock

I would look at other React Native packages that the community has done to wrap custom native UI elements as a starting point to doing that, like for example: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient

In addition, here's Auth0's documentation on how they customize it: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock-ios/customization

Comment: Thank you very much.
I found a solution from https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock/issues/5.
links you listed have been a big help.
I added some code snippet regarding theme within ios/AppDelegate.m then UI just has been changed.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by passing style property to each component,
F.e:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
(...)
render (){
  return (
    <NameOfComponent styles={styles.nameOfStyle}
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  nameOfStyle: {
    fontsize: 10,
  },
});
```

Comment: Wow. Please check https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock.
You didn't understand what I mean.